# nginx with two node aplications with socket IO

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I have two applications running on the same machine. One listens on port 8080 and the other on 11180. SSL connection to the application on port 8080 works but i am having trouble setting up the other one.

To separate the requests heading to each of the applications, one is available at https://example.com and the other at https://example.com/v2

As I said, going to https://example.com works as intended, but going to https://example.com/v2 serves the correct html files but connects to the same server as going to https://example.com

I honestly have no idea what i am doing with nginx, but my config looks like this.

```
   server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /v2/ {

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11180/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /socket.io {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      #proxy_redirect off;

    }

  }
```

It is worth mentioning that the first app listens on 8080 and its socket io on 8081, as for the second app, everything listens on 11180

Thanks a bunch in advance

Comment: What do you mean saying "going to `https://example.com/v2` serves the correct html files but connects to the same server as going to `https://example.com`"? You are getting right index file but all assets requests going to the first app?

Comment: Yes, the correct index.html is served (as well as all partials), but all requests go to the first node process. I believe that it is something to do with the /socket.io location, but am not sure what to do

Comment: How do you create your socket instance? just like `io()`?

Comment: No, I use io.connect() without parameters in both applications. This line is in a file called services.js (for angular js), and I believe that the incorrect file is served, which then causes the faulty connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding another server block to the nginx config, and accessing it via www.example.com:port.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer say you could create a new server block... or you can even create a new conf file in the sites-available folder for the new domain with a new server block. Dont forget to link them to sites-enabled.